# pd.concat + цикл - как подружить?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

Доброго времени суток!

Есть датафрейм

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'A': [16, 10, 17, 23, 8, 34],
                   'B': [23, 9, 45, 39, 15, 1],
                   'C': [33, 81, 11, 55, 26, 90],
                   'X': [10, 12, 12, 14, 13, 18],
                   'Y': [7, 7, 8, 13, 7, 4],
                   'Z': [11, 8, 10, 6, 6, 5]})
```

В нем считаю сумму произведений каждого столбца на столбец A

```
df = pd.concat([df , pd.DataFrame({'B': [df ['B'].mul(df ['A']).sum()],
                                   'C': [df ['C'].mul(df ['A']).sum()],
                                   'X': [df ['X'].mul(df ['A']).sum()],
                                   'Y': [df ['Y'].mul(df ['A']).sum()],
                                   'Z': [df ['Z'].mul(df ['A']).sum()]})])
```

Получаю результат как нужно))

```
A      B      C    X    Y    Z
16.0  23    33    10    7   11
10.0  9     81    12    7   8
17.0  45    11    12    8   10
23.0  39    55    14    13  6
8.0   15    26    13    7   6
34.0  1     90    18    4   5
NaN   2274  6058  1522  809 782
```

Вопрос в том, как сюда можно применить цикл или что еще имея список столбцов (нужно применять именно этот список, т.к. он периодически меняется) чтобы не писать код на каждую строку?

Answer (score 2):

Есть впечатление, что вы не совсем понимаете всей прелести векторизованного подхода pandas. попробуйте так:

```
res = df.append(df.loc[:, df.columns != "A"]
                .mul(df["A"], axis=0).sum(), ignore_index=True)
```

res:

```
      A       B       C       X      Y      Z
0  16.0    23.0    33.0    10.0    7.0   11.0
1  10.0     9.0    81.0    12.0    7.0    8.0
2  17.0    45.0    11.0    12.0    8.0   10.0
3  23.0    39.0    55.0    14.0   13.0    6.0
4   8.0    15.0    26.0    13.0    7.0    6.0
5  34.0     1.0    90.0    18.0    4.0    5.0
6   NaN  2274.0  6058.0  1522.0  809.0  782.0
```

и еще: зачем вы пытаетесь впихнуть в датафрейм результат вычислений, да еще и таким способом?